# jQTouch alert/confim

Tags: jqtouch

I am trying to implement alert/confirm with jQTouch.

Has anyone worked on it, please help me in solving this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So, the way I found works is this:

```
$('.selector').bind('tap', function(){
    var confirm_result = confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');

    if(confirm_result != true){
        return false;
    }
});
```

If the user hits 'Cancel', the page will remain exactly where it is. You may also have to remove the `active` class from the selector (which, in my use-case, was an `<a>` element). That element should have an `href` set to the page which you want to navigate to next.

I realize this is probably way past the statute of limitations for this question, but I figure anyone who comes here looking for the answer will stand to benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar and initially found jGrowl which is a jQuery plugin. Unfortunately jQTouch doesn't appear to play nice with jGrowl which to be honest felt a little hefty anyway for use in a jQTouch app.

Digging a little further I finally found a reference to [floaty](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/Extensions) which is included in the extensions folder of the standard jQTouch release (doh).

<del>Check out [this post](http://www.johnsy.co.uk/?p=125) for a useful example</del>. Sorry, domain expired, post has disappeared. But you can check out [the floaty demo](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/ext_floaty/#test).

Comment: I can't get floaty to work. Don't know what I'm doing wrong but it doesn't want to work when I try it locally.

Comment: Hi Philip - unfortunately you're not providing enough context for me to respond. Maybe you could ask a new question and provide some more detail or example code. Bearing in mind my comment is now over a year old but floaty did work well for me in the mobile app I was working on.